# Select everything from two table based on the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, relational-database

I have two tables:

base_profile:
id, first_name, last_name, address

flight_profile:
id, flight_no, destination

How do i select all fields from these two tables based on the same id?
My assumption would be :

```
SELECT * 
FROM base_profile, flight_profile WHEN base_profile.id == flight_profile.id 
WHERE id, first_name,last_name,address,flight_no,destination
```

I know this is not right. Can anyone help me to correct it please? Thanks.

Comment: SELECT * FROM base_profile, flight_profile WHERE base_profile.id == flight_profile.id;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an `inner join`

```
SELECT base_profile.id, base_profile.first_name, base_profile.last_name, base_profile.address,
      flight_profile.flight_no,flight_profile.destination
FROM base_profile INNER JOIN  flight_profile
     ON base_profile.id = flight_profile.id
```

or more generally

```
SELECT <fields you want to return>
FROM <tables linked with joins>
```

Answer (score 2):

How to select inner join where ID = 1 from (sample) above code

```
SELECT base_profile.id, 
       base_profile.first_name, 
       base_profile.last_name, 
       base_profile.address, 
       flight_profile.flight_no, 
       flight_profile.destination 
FROM   base_profile 
       INNER JOIN flight_profile 
               ON base_profile.id = flight_profile.id 
WHERE  base_profile.id = 1
```